# How can I do string translation on the windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

If I have something like 
`set value = c:\\some\\path`

I want to convert this to 
`c:\some\path`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) you can use string replace.

```
@echo off
set value=c:\\some\\path
echo %value%
set new_value=%value:\\=\%
echo %new_value%
```

output

```
c:\\some\\path
c:\some\path
```

(yes I just learned this trick too)

That Link also has

```
Align Right          Align text to the right i.e. to improve readability of number columns.
Left String          Extract characters from the beginning of a string.
Map and Lookup       Use Key-Value pair list to lookup and translate values.
Mid String           Extract a Substring by Position.
Remove               Remove a substring using string substitution.
Remove both Ends     Remove the first and the last character of a string.
Remove Spaces        Remove all spaces in a string via substitution.
Replace              Replace a substring using string substitution.
Right String         Extract characters from the end of a string.
Split String         Split a String, Extract Substrings by Delimiters.
String Concatenation Add one string to another string.
Trim Left            Trim spaces from the beginning of a string via "FOR" command.
Trim Quotes          Remove surrounding quotes via FOR command.
Trim Right           Trim spaces from the end of a string via substitution.
Trim Right           Trim spaces from the end of a string via "FOR" command.
```

Comment: What did you google to find it btw?

Comment: I googled: "windows batch strip" it was the the last on the page!

Comment: Or type "help set" in cmd.exe :-).